# Change Key binds for Simcity

Tags: simcity-2013

For the life of me I can't find anything about changing key bindings for the new SimCity... I've always used "v" for voice chat in TeamSpeak and I don't want to rebind... I've looked and looked and I can't find out how to change the binding for "v" in SimCity for the annoying video recording.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the key bindings in SimCity currently. There are a [few posts](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Miscellaneous-Issues/Unable-to-Find-Keybinding-Options/td-p/603366) on EA's forums asking for this as a feature but as of yet nothing has been confirmed.